# Summing in Javascript over three columns instead of one using lines.reduce

Tags: javascript

My dataset is a .csv file that I am loading in, and then summing over the values of one column (the first column).  How would I modify this chunk of code that will allow me to sum over 3 columns?

I am pulling in a .csv from a SQL query which has just one column.  But I would like to pull in three columns and store the sum of the 3 columns in `this.sum`.

```
   // convert our data from the file into an array
    var lines = data.replace(/\n+$/, "").split("\n");

    // we have array of strings but need an array of Numbers this should do the trick getting rid of any text and 0 values


    lines = lines.map(Number).filter(Boolean);

    // now we find the sum of all of the values in our array.

    this.sum = lines.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

**Edit:**
My current dataset is simply just a column (with a header) and a sum of all of the rows below.  Each of the other two columns would be the same.

```
column1
10
12
145
0
13
0
0
0
15
16
```

Comment: Adding a sample of the csv data you are working with would be helpful